# PL/SQL: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here; DISTINCT subquery issues with REGEXP and CONNECT BY

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, distinct, plsqldeveloper

I am attempting to populate a bridge table with existing numeric `IDs` (`VARIABLE_ID` field) and strings (`DETAILS` field) that are in the format `averaged; smoothed` per cell. I've split the strings on `;` using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `CONNECT BY`, which works. When I try to insert the values into the new table,

```
INSERT INTO PC_VARIABLES_DETAILS_BRIDGE (DETAIL_BRIDGE_ID, VARIABLE_ID, THE_DETAIL)
SELECT DISTINCT PC_VAR_DETAILS_BRIDGE_PK.NEXTVAL, e.VARIABLE_ID, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.DETAILS,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) FROM (SELECT VARIABLE_ID, DETAILS FROM EG_VAR_UPLOAD_TEST WHERE DETAILS IS NOT NULL) e
CONNECT BY TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.DETAILS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL;
```

I get the error `PL/SQL: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`, which makes sense. When I nest `DISTINCT` into the `FROM` clause (`SELECT DISTINCT VARIABLE_ID...FROM...`) it runs but I get a fundamentally different output.

Appealing to only the `SELECT` clause, what I want is

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.VARIABLE_ID E_VARIABLE_ID, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.DETAILS,'[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) THE_DETAIL FROM (SELECT VARIABLE_ID, DETAILS FROM EG_VAR_UPLOAD_TEST WHERE DETAILS IS NOT NULL) e
        CONNECT BY TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.DETAILS, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY e.VARIABLE_ID;
```

which yields multiple `IDs` only if they are associated with multiple `DETAILS` in one cell (e.g., `averaged; smoothed`), **which is what I want and it runs**:

[image]

But, again, when I nest `DISTINCT` into the `FROM` clause, I get multiple `IDs` and multiple `DETAILS` (in fact, the total number of rows matches that of the table they are in):

[image]

Is there something under the hood I'm not seeing? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need one more level in your select. Once you've gathered all of the distinct values, select all of them and add in the sequence call in an outer query. For example:

```
INSERT INTO pc_variables_details_bridge
   (detail_bridge_id
   ,variable_id
   ,the_detail)
   SELECT pc_var_details_bridge_pk.nextval
         ,variable_id
         ,the_detail
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT e.variable_id
                          ,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.details, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) the_detail
             FROM (SELECT variable_id
                         ,details
                     FROM eg_var_upload_test
                    WHERE details IS NOT NULL) e
           CONNECT BY TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(e.details, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: That did it--thanks! I'd probably get there eventually, but I figured it'd be quicker to ask you guys (it was). Marked as correct.